Find a fragment in the whole image
Globally, my task is to determine the similarity / dissimilarity of two .jpg files.
Below I will describe the process in more detail. I have five (in reality there are more) template .jpg files. And I have a new .jpg file, which I must match with each template .jpg file to make a decision - is the new .jpg file similar to any of the template .jpg files or not.
Correlating entire files in my case is a bad idea, since the error is large. So I came up with a way to "cut" the new file into 12 equal parts (fragments) (that is, into 12 .jpg files) and search for each individual fragment in the template.
For this, I used the tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html
But the problem is that the fragments from the new .jpg file are extremely incorrectly matched with the template.
Below I will show an example:
Let's take the document below as a template

And the document below as a new document (schematically I cut it into 12 parts, that is, I receive one document as input, but I cut this one document into 12 parts (fragments) (that is, 12 new files))

Next, take a look at my code. The gist of it is that I take each of the 12 fragments and search for that fragment in the template
def match_slices_in_template(path_template):
    directory_in_str = 'slices'
    directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

    img1 = cv.imread(path_template, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # queryImage

    good = []
    for slice_image in os.listdir(directory):
        print(slice_image)
        filename = os.fsdecode(slice_image)
        img2 = cv.imread(f'slices/{filename}', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # trainImage

        # Initiate SIFT detector
        sift = cv.SIFT_create()

        # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
        kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
        kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

        # BFMatcher with default params
        bf = cv.BFMatcher()
        matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

        # Apply ratio test
        for m, n in matches:
            if m.distance < 0.3 * n.distance:
                good.append([m])

        # cv.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
        img3 = cv.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

        plt.imshow(img3), plt.show()

print(match_slices_in_template('Bill_1.jpg'))

But the search result is completely incorrect, take a look at some sample graphs that matplotlib built



In my example, in fact, the two files are different (although they have a lot in common). But the program identifies them as quite similar.
So you probably understand the essence of my question: how to improve the performance of the algorithm so that it would determine similarity/difference more accurately than now

matching isn't enough. you forgot the stuff that comes after. -- those fragments are very bare, almost featureless. that's a bad situation to have. don't do that. match on the whole page.

@Thanks for the advice. And then what do you think, if I remove all the text from the .jpg file beforehand, i.e. leave only the table in the document. And compare it with the table from another .jpg file. leaving the concept of this question the same (cutting the new file into fragments). Will it be more effective or not?

removing variable text (filled in content) but keeping fixed text (form labels and descriptions) would make sense. -- cutting into fragments makes no sense. you said "the error is large", which is neither demonstrated nor argued. -- you still haven't discussed the mandatory step that comes after matching. did you follow any material that stops after matching and drawing the matches? then you're looking at the wrong material.

@ChristophRackwitz And what step should come after the comparison, please tell me?

fitting a model to a subset of the matches. one approach uses RANSAC. the model may be a homography or a lesser transform. findHomography is the function to use. that's not the end of it either. because RANSAC is probabilistic, you'd want to assess the model fit for plausibility. if you have scans, the homography should have no perspective, there should be no stretching (i.e. scaling is equal), and if the scan was put in right side up, there should be no rotation. alternatively, the template's corners mapped onto the scan should roughly hit the scan's corners, and vice versa.

you should have proceeded from the tutorial you linked onto the next one: https://i.sstatic.net/jtd4eStF.png (find that list one level up from the link in your question). yes the docs could be better, in that they should link to the next tutorial right at the bottom of a preceding one.

Globally, my task is to determine the similarity / dissimilarity of two .jpg files, I think that given the goal, your approach is not really gonna work for all cases. E.g, look at that bottom centre piece, structurly they have almost nothing in common with the base image. I would rather go with OCR on the whole image and then use the words to classify the documents, I might write up an example...

you just removed vital data from the post. this makes the question useless to anyone but you. however, having value to others is a requirement of questions on this site. please reconsider.

I wrote up an example to guide you in the direction of classifying by relying on text instead of structural similarity between the documents.
My folder is organized like this:

I have two training images and three test images. The training images are in the template folder and the images I want to classify are in the toBeClassified folder. Here are my input images:

Now that we got that out of the way, here's a function that can get text from the images:
def text_from_image(filename):
    '''
    Load image as grayscale by using cv2.irmead(_, 0)
    extract text using pytesseract, we use the text for classification
    '''
    imGray = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imGray)
    return text

Now that we have the text, we can use it together with some labels that we put as training reponses to train the model:
texts = [text_from_image("Templates/"+filename) for filename in os.listdir("Templates/")] # get the texts
labels = ["Shipping", "Invoice"] # label the texts

These lines are used to get the model and to train it on the templates:
model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB()) # init the model
model.fit(texts, labels) # fit the model

Now we can go with two approaches, either we are just satisfied with the class with the highest probability or we go with predicting the probabilities.
The first approach:
def classify_with_model(filename, model):
    '''
    We pass the filename of the images to be classified and the model to get the 
    class with the highest probability, not very good but good for now
    '''
    text = text_from_image(filename)
    category = model.predict([text])[0]
    return category

If we loop through the test images, we get:
for filename in os.listdir("toBeClassified/"): # loop through the test images
    category = classify_with_model("toBeClassified/"+filename, model) # get the class with the highest prob
    print(f'Document {filename} is classified as {category}') # print out results

# Document Bill1.png is classified as Invoice
# Document Shipping1.jpg is classified as Shipping
# Document ShippingInvoice1.png is classified as Invoice

Notice the last image, is kind of a hybrid that I found online. So looking at the probabilities is quite essential in some cases. As the joke when it comes to SVM learners: A healthy person goes to the doctor for a cancer screening. The doctor uses a state-of-the-art SVM machine learning model with 100% accuracy in identifying different types of cancer. After the test, the doctor comes back and says, "Good news and bad news. The good news: our model is perfect at diagnosing every type of cancer. The bad news: it doesn't know how to say you're healthy."

In any case, no time for humour, or my attempt at it. We go with probabilities:
def classify_with_probability(filename, model):
    '''
    This is to classify with probability, a bit better to see the confidences
    '''
    text = text_from_image(filename)
    probabilities = model.predict_proba([text])[0]  # get probabilities for each class
    categories = model.classes_  # get the class labels
    bestMatchIdx = probabilities.argmax()  # index of the highest probability
    bestMatch = categories[bestMatchIdx]  # class with the highest probability
    confidence = probabilities[bestMatchIdx]  # probability of the best match
    return bestMatch, dict(zip(categories, probabilities)) # return everythin

And the results are:
for filename in os.listdir("toBeClassified/"):
    category = classify_with_probability("toBeClassified/"+filename, model)
    print(f'Document {filename} is classified as {category[0]} with the following confidence:')
    print(category[1])
    print("_______________________")
#Document Bill1.png is classified as Invoice with the following confidence:
#{'Invoice': 0.5693790615221315, 'Shipping': 0.4306209384778673}
#_______________________
#Document Shipping1.jpg is classified as Shipping with the following confidence:
#{'Invoice': 0.38458825025403914, 'Shipping': 0.6154117497459587}
#_______________________
#Document ShippingInvoice1.png is classified as Invoice with the following confidence:
#{'Invoice': 0.5519774748181495, 'Shipping': 0.4480225251818504}
#_______________________

Here, we see the probabilities as well, this can be helpful if you want to classify your images into multiple clases at the same time, e.g., invoice and shipping form.
I hope this helps you in some way, as I said, and as Christoph mentioned, going with features on those documents will be a wild attempt.
The imports:
import cv2
import pytesseract
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import os
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"


Thank you very much for paying attention to my question, and also thank you for such a detailed answer. Of course, I need time to read and understand how everything works here. I will come back to you!

Sure thing @Paul, let me know if you have any questions!

Firstly, I appreciated your joke)) You are quite a funny person. Secondly, I started to learning your code and have several questions about the second approach (predicting the probabilities):


in the classify_with_probability function, the last variable confidence is not used anywhere. Is it necessary? 2) in the next part of the code there is a line f'Document {filename} is classified as {category[0]} with the following confidence:' and immediately below the line where the probabilities are displayed relative to each template. I am a little confused: either I did not correctly understand the course of your thoughts or you wrote something wrong



you can remove that line, this information is returned anyway in zip(categoties, probabilities) @Paul



am not sure what you mean? The idea here is that you take the class with the highest probability, but it is also important to see the probabilities of all classes. This is why you see the categories with their respective proba to the right @Paul Do ask more if you're still not sure about anything


Yes, I already understood this point. Sorry, I didn't understand it completely before asking.

Interesting, can you tell me why two completely identical documents are classified with a probability of 0.5-0.6, but not with a probability of 1?

I'll have to see the images and check for myself. Though I think you did not really get the methodology behind the approach. If some words are found in both template documents, the probability might be high on both trained classes. These words can also be removed (date, address, name). If you would like to discuss this further, I suggest we go to chat

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
